# How to quickly change the language in the latest Swype beta?

Tags: languages, swype

According to [Swype's advanced tips page](http://www.swype.com/tips/advanced-tips/):

> Switching languages: To switch between the two most recent languages, Swype from the Swype-key to the key with the language initials on it.

Since I updated Swype, the language initials are on the space bar and this tip doesn't work any more. I can still switch languages by long-pressing the space bar but that's a hassle. What's the new quick way to change the language?

Here's a screenshot of the keyboard as it looks like for me:
[image: Swype keyboard with no dedicated language switching key]

Answer (score 0):

May I ask which version of Swype beta are you using?

For my version 1.0.3.5809, the official documents said:

> To Switch languages from the keyboard: Press and hold the space bar
>   Select your desired language from the pop-up menu

[image]

Comment: I have the same version. But anything involving "press and hold" is definitely not quick.

Comment: @Erik then u can try pressing the language button next to the "comma", it's definitely quicker than the "official" method

Comment: I don't have such a button any more since the update. See the screenshot I added to my question.

Comment: @Erik ok, I know why ur keyboard doesn't have the button I am saying. It is because u only got Deutsch selected. Please go to Swype settings and choose at least two languages, then the button I described will show up.

Comment: @Erik oops, sorry, I didn't noticed that the button is for the Chinese keyboard to switch between Chinese and English only.

Answer (score 0):

In my version I simply Swype from the Swype key to the space bar.